# How to add ConTeXt to an existing Windows TeX Live installation?

Tags: texlive, context, windows

I have TeX Live installed on Windows already and have been using LaTeX. I want to try out ConTeXt. But TLShell doesn't seem to have any way to install ConTeXt and trying to run the TeX Live install again warns "directory not empty - may cause trouble!". How do I proceed?

Note: while installing TeX Live originally I probably chose a more minimal setting to preserve my disk space, so ConTeXt doesn't seem to have been installed already.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I would install from [here](http://www.pragma-ade.com/install.htm) instead. That will give you the latest version. I am not even sure if ConTeXt lmtx is shipped with texlive.